# (PHP + MongoDB + Laravel jenssegers) Failed to send "count" command with database: socket error or timeout

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I have been running MongoDB in my Amazon since 2019. It has over millions of data and it was working fine until yesterday. But today when I try to query using Laravel jenssegers eloquent model it gives me this error:

```
Failed to send "count" command with database "<database>": socket error or timeout

at /var/www/html/console/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Count.php:154
150| if (isset($this->options['readConcern']) && ! \MongoDB\server_supports_feature($server, self::$wireVersionForReadConcern)) {
151| throw UnsupportedException::readConcernNotSupported();
152| }
153|

154| $cursor = $server->executeReadCommand($this->databaseName, new Command($this->createCommandDocument()), $this->createOptions());
155| $result = current($cursor->toArray());
156|
157| // Older server versions may return a float
158| if ( ! isset($result->n) || ! (is_integer($result->n) || is_float($result->n))) {

Exception trace:

1 MongoDB\Driver\Server::executeReadCommand("dddb", Object(MongoDB\Driver\Command), [Object(MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference)])
/var/www/html/console/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Count.php:154

2 MongoDB\Operation\Count::execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server))
/var/www/html/console/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php:277

Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: The error "socket error or timeout" suggests that Mongo is not listening. Try restarting the MongoDB server. Do you host that yourself or is that an AWS cloud product?

Comment: When I try to search/count small data with limit e.g. 100, then it works fine. Only it shows the error when I try to do that for large data. e.g. 1M. Yes I did host that myself on AWS EC2 Instance @halfer

Comment: OK. Have a look at the GitHub issues for the library `mongodb/mongodb` - maybe there will be some suitable bug reports there. I tried a search engine search for your error, and couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: You might also want to check the disk on the Mongo server. Is it the same VPS as your web server, or is it separate?

Comment: I wonder if your timeout setting is too low - maybe it is a slow operation and you need to increase this, either in the server or PHP client settings?

Comment: mongod is running in the same server as my web server. as I said, it was working find until yesterday. How to increase timeout for mongodb in PHP client settings? @halfer

Comment: You can find out by running a search engine search for "How to increase timeout for mongodb in PHP". A good tip with researching things is to talk to a search engine as if it were a human - they are quite good at matching natural language these days.

Comment: I would guess your database has become slower because of the amount of data in it, and the last inserts pushed it over the edge. Consider also moving your MongoDB instance to a separate (and faster) server.